# Converting .py to .exe in python 2.5: doesnt execute .exe program directly

Tags: python, console-application, executable

I have successfully converted my .py script to .exe but the problem is that it wont get executed when I press the .exe icon. A black screen pops up for a fraction of a second and then disappears.

I tried executing it through the command prompt and it did get executed but doesn't run if I click the .exe directly. Just want to know if there is some error in placing the .exe file due to which I am encountering this problem.

```
    # setup.py
    from distutils.core import setup
    import py2exe
    setup(console=["myscript.py"])
    python setup.py py2exe --help
    python setup.py py2exe
```

Comment: Now when i put this .exe program on my desktop instead of the folder where my .py script is, it gives the same error of opening a black screen for a second and then closing it :( despite using raw_input. Is there some error in placement of .exe file on desktop...what is the mistake now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shell disappears because the program finishes.
End your program with a `raw_input('enter to finish')` line and the console will stay allowing you to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it got executed when you ran it from command prompt?  If the app just outputs something and exits, you will see the behavior you are describing: the black window will flash and disappear.  That the same as running any other win32 console app from windows explorer.

Comment: using command prompt displays the "result" of the script...for eg: if my script "myscript.py" is counting 10 numbers....then i'll get the o/p displayed on prompt window i.e. 10

Comment: Well, then you need to wait for user input before the program exits.  Or create a gui application using TkIntel or WxPython.

Comment: i need to take user input actually. bcoz makin a GUI isnt what i want. my script is not a GUI script.